# Emacs C-c C-, doesn't work in a "terminal"

Tags: terminal, emacs

I need to send my Emacs the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (`C-c C-,` in Emacs notation) via SSH shell or a terminal emulation (e.g. [`terminator`](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/terminator)).

But it seems that `C-,` doesn't work.

First I thought this is because of SSH because I use it quit often. But I can reproduce the problem also in a usual local `terminator` window on Debian stable running non GUI Emacs via `emacs -nw`.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: The windows command prompt is the terminal, isn't it?